# Trying to explore connected shop floor use case and need advice on an IOT architecture

Tags: iot

Apologies if this question ends up being very general and broad. IoT is new and upcoming with people still trying to figure it out so I decided to take a chance and ask my question.

I looked at the legacy and current applications being used on the shop floor and reached an understanding that at the very low level (device layer) we have PLC/SCADA that needs to communicate with OPC(OLE for process control) Source Agent(Server) to store data as PLCs are real time with no storage capability. Then we use a Plant Connectivity tool like SAP to query the OPC and pass on that information to an MII(Management Intelligence Integration) tool.

1. Connected shop floor in the context of IoT would basically be a
   direct communication between PLCs and IIM with some sort of
   intelligent layer in between right?
2. Coming from an IT standpoint where hardware is a blackbox what
   should be kept in mind while building a dashboard as far as sensors
   and the device layer is concerned?
3. Should I be looking at all the gazillion sensors being used on the
   shop floor and design a dashboard that incorporates a majority of
   them?
4. What standards should I follow?
5. Where can I get opensource data from shop floor sensor
   (temp,humidity,vibration,CNC laithe data, PLC data etc)?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice/encouragement.

Comment: Hi Serendipity, correct me if i am wrong, but from what i understand, you want to read some sensor data and transmit it using Internet of Things, right ??

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Thanks for the reply. I asked this question last year and figured some stuff out over the past several months and have created a few POCs in the retail and healthcare space. However, I would still like to explore the IM use case for IoT and you are correct, its basically reading sensor data, transmit it plus do analysis over it. There are several tools now which enable one to do that quickly like IBM Bluemix but the piece that still confounds me is how does one even begin to measure sensor data in legacy IM systems and what exactly should one measure besides ambient conditions.

Comment: Hi Serendipity, i have developed a Wifi-IoT based product that monitors heart rate and temperature of patient and sends this data to remote server for monitoring. I suppose your problem is more about measuring sensor data in legacy IM systems, which i haven't worked with. I have worked more on the IoT aspect. I'll see if i can answer your problem regarding what else to measure besides ambient conditions.

Comment: Cool! Are you using a phone to monitor heart rate or did you create your own heart rate sensor? Could you extend that to monitor heart rate variability? thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, i am using an android based application to monitor heart rate and Electrocardiogram. Currently i am working on analysis of Electrocardiogram. I haven't used heart rate sensor, i have used 12-lead ECG to calculate heart rate. HRV is not a concern now since i am designing the product for home-care.